# Nested dropdown list without named ranges

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, excel

I'm a newbie, so your patience is appreciated. I have a long list of case numbers and associated names in one sheet, with several names per case number. At various places in the workbook, I want users to pick a case number from a dropdown list (can use dynamic named ranges), and then select one of the associated names in another dropdown.

Because there are so many case numbers, and they change, I can't use a named range for the second dropdown. Is there a VBA way to do this?

Comment: How are your case numbers and associated names arranged?

Comment: How about just using a filter?

Comment: The spreadsheet will be a live document for users not versed in Excel, so I don't think I can use filters. The spreadsheet needs to update itself constantly (i.e. new case numbers and names are added by the user, and the dropdown lists need to correspond accordingly). Unless I don't understand filters well enough...

Comment: The options available with a filter will update automatically. I don't know if it will work for you, but it is very easy to try: select the range (could be whole columns), then select the Data tab and the Filter button. Done. (In VBA, just as simple - `Range("A1:C4").AutoFilter`) (Excel 2010)

Comment: I think I see what you mean: I can use a dynamic range on a filtered list, to populate my dropdown list (which is on another sheet). The filter is defined by content of the first dropdown list. That would be a neat solution, will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your case numbers are in row 1 of Sheet2, with their associated names below each case number, that your case number dropdown is in cell `B1` and your associated name dropdown in cell `B2` (defined as a datavalidation with the list ListNames), use the following worksheet macro to update the data validation for `B2`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rgNames As Range, rgFoundCase As Range

If Not Intersect(Target, [B1]) Is Nothing Then

    'turn off updates to speed up code execution
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Set rgFoundCase = Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).Find(What:=[B1], After:=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Set rgNames = rgFoundCase.Offset(1).Resize(rgFoundCase.End(xlDown).Row - 1)

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ListNames", RefersTo:=rgNames

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks nutsch, I've managed to adapt this to work. Thanks for your help.